# What does "would be caught dead with somebody" mean?

Tags: meaning

https://youtu.be/dmV4IzJZEVs

What does "nobody would be caught dead with you." mean?

I guess it means "nobody is dying for you" or "nobody loves you". Am I right or not?

Comment: Note that, as you gave it in the title, without the negative polarity item "nobody", it is nonsensical. It's an idiom which is only ever used in the negative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement means that other people would rather die than to be seen in your company.

Such hyperbole makes the point that you are not very popular.

There are several words that refer to people who have been rejected by society, such as pariah, outcast, persona non grata, untouchable.

However the statement is generally just an expression of somebody's strong feelings, especially when expressed on social media.

Comment: I've always felt that saying you wouldn't be caught (or 'seen' in the UK) dead doing something (eating in MacDonald's, driving a Ford, wearing yellow, etc) was a hyperbolic way of saying that even after you were dead, (when in fact you aren't able to care about or resent anything), you would dislike to be seen doing the named thing.